# inner working of asynchronous block in iOS program?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I am using the following method to browse the photos library in iPhone:

```
enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:
```

From the API doc and my test, I know the block runs asynchronously. However, my question is: how exactly this block runs asynchronously?

I.e. does it run via the same runloop as the main thread? or via a new & different runloop?

also, does it run in a new & different thread?  (assuming 'thread' is not same as 'runloop')

Let's say that I want to do something to update the view(UI) inside the block, particularly do a :

```
[collectionView reloadData].
```

How will this "reloadData" message be handled? Will it be handled in the same runloop as the block itself?  [Update question: will this "reloadData" be asynchronous or synchronous relative to this block's execution?]

And at last, in case I am asking dumb questions, can anyone suggest a book or other pointers to understand the inner working of  asynchronous block in iOS program, e.g. how it's related to runloops and threads?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the block is called on the main queue (running on the main thread)
2. no special runloop mode or so is entered ...

you can see it when you write a simple demo app

either the ALAssetFramework uses GCD dispatch or it registers as a source for runloop events.. but thats an implementation detail

about the update:

a block is a little like a regular function... so reloadData is synchronous normally and it will remain synchronous when used in a block therefore

Comment: Thanks. From my testing, it looks like : 1) the block is executed when the main thread has spare time. 2) the block is executed as a single step, i.e. there is no parallel execution between the main thread and this block.

Comment: and about a good book.. im not sure.. but most up-to-date iOS coding books have a section about GCD. that should work

Comment: @user1783732 no the main_queue is SERIAL -- there can ever only be one function -- one block and there is way to advance the runloop in between unless you call it yourself IN that function